# Download CSV through REST Api

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, csv

I have to download CSV from REST Api.
I'm doing Http get request through my service

user.service.ts

```
  public downloadCsv(target: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      this.api.getUrl(environment.api.endpoints.download).replace('{target}', target)
    ).pipe(
      catchError(this.api.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and subscribe into observable in my component

customer-list.component.ts

```
  downloadCsv() {
    this.userService.downloadCsv('users_ub').subscribe(
      (response) => {

      }
    );
  }
```

I get an error

```
VM73806 vendor.js:56089 ERROR Error Code: 200
Message: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:90/api/download/csv/users_ub.csv
```

Request data in chrome dev tools (angular)
[image]

request data from my api docs

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{ responseType: 'blob' }`

```
this.http.get<any>(url,{ responseType: 'blob' })
```